# Launch emulator from second Activity android eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-activity

I have 2 `Activity` files. 1 activity is for `Setup` and other is for  `main`.

In one `Activity` I have a code to show phone number device so if user has ever `setup` he will forward in second activity .
I Need to start with `Setup` Activity.

Can you tell me , how to make it?

Comment: You need to start with `Setup` or `Main` `Activity`? or moving from `Main` `Activity` to setup `Activity`? what you want in these two?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear please ? Are you trying to pass a value from the first activity to the second ?

Comment: for the first , user will launch Setup Activity to insert his email and he will go to main Activity , But if he has insert his email before , when he open this application, he will forward to main Activity not setup Activity again , can u give solution?? thanks

Comment: so what you want is if the user ever entered a emai you should go to the 2n activity is that what you want--- for that a normal solution is adding a splash screen and checking wether the user have any saved emails (probably in shared pref) and launching which ever activity corresponding to the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your application with the Setup Activity. Define [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to check if the user has already entered the email or not. If there is no email present, ask the user for the email and store it in the SharedPreferences and proceed to the next Activity.

Next time when the application is started, you will find the email in the SharedPreference string variable and hence go to the next activity directly.

Something like this :

```
public void onCreate(){
    String user_email = getSharedPreference("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("userEmail",null);
    if (user_email == null){
   [Get the email from the User, something like xyz@example.com and store it in a String userEmail]
   String userEmail = ....//input email from user 
    // Save the state
    getSharedPreference("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
        .edit()
        .putString("userEmail", userEmail)
        .commit();
    }
}
```